# C++ Compile error on lines that do not exist

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors

so i'm doing a uni project and when i try to compile a weird error pops up.I've read it might be from circular dependencies but i've checked and thats not the problem here's the header code :

```
#ifndef __ScheduleHeader_H_INCLUDED__
#define __ScheduleHeader_H_INCLUDED__

#include "TrainStationHeader.h"

class Schedule
{
friend class ScheduleIterator;
  public:
    //get data functions
    std::string getFromCity() { return fromCity; }
    std::string getToCity() { return toCity; }
    std::string getTrainID() { return trainID; }
    std::string getDate();
    std::string getTime();
    std::string getTimeForTickets();
    std::string getPrice() { return price; }    

    //set data functions + validation on the input data
    bool setFromCity();
    bool setToCity();
void setDate();
    void setTime();
    bool setTrainID();
    void setPrice();

    std::string createScheduleLine();

private:
    int validateDate(struct tm,struct tm);
    int validateTime(struct tm,struct tm);

    std::string scheduleFileName;
    std::string fromCity;
    std::string toCity;
    struct tm dateAndTime;
    std::string trainID;
    std::string price;
};

#endif
```

I've added the friend because i have a Schedule object in another class as private.The error when i compile is :

```
c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\um\schedule.h(60): error C2146: syntax         error : missing ';' before identifier 'Type'
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\um\schedule.h(60): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\um\schedule.h(61): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'Offset'
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\um\schedule.h(61): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\um\schedule.h(68): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'Size'
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\um\schedule.h(68): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\um\schedule.h(69): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'Bandwidth'
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\um\schedule.h(69): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\um\schedule.h(70): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'NumberOfSchedules'
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\um\schedule.h(70): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

PS:I'm using MC VS 2012

here's the TrainStation.h , Its just a bunch of functions and libraries i use across the majority of the classes (i know it's not the best practice) :

```
#ifndef __TrainStation_H_INCLUDED__
#define __TrainStation_H_INCLUDED__

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <locale>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

std::string removeWhiteSpace(std::string a);

//Resieves the file on wich to operate upon and what to search for.
//If it finds it it returns the line on wich it has been found ,if not returns -1
int checkContent(std::string FileName, std::string target);

//Give the Function the File Name with wich you would like to work and the target that             you would like to delete
//It works by copying everything exept the target string to another file then renames it and deletes the old file
int deleteContent(std::string File,std::string target);

void renameFile(std::string , std::string);

bool checkFileState(std::ifstream &file);
#endif
```

Comment: And there's no missing semicolon or similar in the `TrainStationHeader.h` header file?

Comment: Nope I checked.Besides i have used it in multiple files before that it worked fine and i haven't touched it

Comment: You should check your include paths, is the file you show really the file you include? If you check the error messages it complaints about things not in the file you show in your question.

Comment: THe error is coming from a different file than this. Please post the contents of `TrainStationHeader.h`

Comment: This isn't the problem, but names that contain two underscores (`__ScheduleHeader_H_INCLUDED__`) and names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved to the implementation. Don't use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error message indicates error in "C:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\um\schedule.h" that is part of installation of VS or additional SDKs. You quote a completely different header file.

If you can't figure out the error, ask for preprocessor output and read that to see the problem. /SHOWINCLUDES may also help.

Comment: The problem was i included a wrong header in my tickets file.Once i went to the dorectory and deleted schedule.h the error became clear